# How to add a new user on Microsoft BizSpark?

Tags: bizspark

I want to check and see who is on the team and add a new user but the manage button is no longer present.

How can I add a user to bizspark?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this address [edit bizspark members](https://portal.startups.microsoft.com/My/Offers)

Answer (score 1):

## Understanding Bizspark

Bizspark and it's replacement Microsoft for Startups can be a little confusing with the fragmentation of the resources. Much of the progress is useful things strapped together for a startup program so it can feel frustrating at times working out what credits you have and how to distribute them.

## Adding team members

As the program has changed over the years, it's useful to think of this now as both the cloud computing side, and the subscription services side. You want to add your team members to the latter - which is the **Visual Studio Subscription Offer**.

Link: https://portal.startups.microsoft.com/My/Offers

## Accessing resources

Once you assign your team member one of the five available licenses, they're good to go. They can now log into the benefits section and jump into training and other perks.

Link: https://my.visualstudio.com/Benefits

And of course for Azure itself.

Link: https://portal.azure.com/#home